# hiding the main Window after opening the secondWindow?Also, when the secondWindow is closed by the user, how can the main window reappear?

Tags: c++, windows, qt

Basically, when second window is opened from a push button in the main window, the main window will be closed. When the second window is closed, the main window will reappear.

```
QWidget *wdg = new QWidget;
    wdg->show();
    hide();
```

I put this under the class of mainwindow.cpp
I tried using this..but it doesn't seem to do anything?

this are the code I have so far. Everything is working but I just don't know how to hide the window when the second window is opened and also when the second window is closed the main window will reappear.

mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();


private slots:
    void on_pushButton_clicked();
public:
    void show();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

secwindow.h

```
#ifndef SECWINDOW_H
#define SECWINDOW_H

#include <QDialog>

namespace Ui {
class SecWindow;
}

class SecWindow : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit SecWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~SecWindow();

private:
    Ui::SecWindow *ui;
};

#endif // SECWINDOW_H
```

source code

main.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QMessageBox>
#include <QPixmap>
#include "secwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    QPixmap pix("C:/Users/Charlene/Downloads/Charlene Back-up/MAPUA/2nd Term/Object Oriented Programming/GOW-Gui/GOW-GUI/intro pic/intro.png");
ui->label->setPixmap(pix.scaled(230,250,Qt::KeepAspectRatio));

}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
   delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked() // Modal approach..mainwindow cannot be moved when secwindow is displayed.
{
    SecWindow secwindow;
    secwindow.setModal(true); //it'll set the secwindow
    secwindow.exec(); //shows secwindow when button is pressed
}
```

secwindow.cpp

```
#include "secwindow.h"
#include "ui_secwindow.h"

SecWindow::SecWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::SecWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

SecWindow::~SecWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

EDIT:

@Serhiy Kulish

What I added so far:

secWindow.h

```
class Dialog : public QDialog
{
  Dialog();
};
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
#include <QDialog> 

void MainWindow::show()  
{
    Dialog *dialog = new Dialog(this); //Error:no matching constructor for initialization of 'Diaolog'
    connect(dialog, SIGNAL(accepted()), this, SLOT(show()));
    connect(dialog, SIGNAL(rejected()), this, SLOT(show()));
    dialog->show();
    hide();
}
```

These are the errors I'm having so far.

Answer (score 0):

Add your own class derived from `QDialog`. Then connect signals `accepted` and `rejected` with `MainWindow::show()`.

```
Dialog *dialog = new Dialog(this);
connect(dialog, SIGNAL(accepted()), this, SLOT(show()));
connect(dialog, SIGNAL(rejected()), this, SLOT(show()));
dialog->show();
hide();
```

It works fine on Windows 10. 
Also, depends your OS you maybe need

```
QApplication a(argc, argv);
a.setQuitOnLastWindowClosed(false);
```

in `main.cpp` to prevent app closing. But in this case you have to quit from your app manually

Comment: Just to clarify, I will add this to my MainWindow.cpp right?

Comment: @Kuushie118 Yes, because `hide()` means `MainWindow::hide()`

Comment: Sir, I will declare the show() in class MainWindow public slot?

I have an error that says:
C++ requires a type specifier for all declarations.

Also, what do you mean by derived from QDialog?

Comment: Do I have to create a class dialog?